# What SQL query returns the row with the most recent Date and Time (Column B and C) for each unique Column A?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group

What SQL query returns the row with the most recent Date and Time (Column B and C) for each unique Column A?

Comment: Is there a unique single-column key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `C` is actually a `datetime` column with date **and** time information set, you can do:

```
select a, max(c)
  from table
 group by a;
```

If `B` is a `date` column and `C` is a `time` column, then you need:

```
select a, max(convert(varchar(15), b) + ' ' + convert(varchar(15), c))
  from table
 group by a;
```

Comment: Thank you!!  Actually B and C are individual date and time(0) fields.

Comment: Pablo, this won't run.  "The data types date and varchar are incompatible in the add operator".

Comment: But this works:   MAX(CONVERT(varchar(15), LogDate) + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar(15), LogTime))

Answer (score 0):

When I do:

```
select convert(varchar, getdate())
```

I get "Nov 19 2010  5:17PM", which doesn't help when finding the max().
I would spell out the style even if your database default doesn't have this problem.  Something like:

```
select x.a,
cast(max(convert(varchar, x.b, 112)+' '+
convert(varchar, x.c, 108) as Datetime)) 
as maxDateTime
from table x
group by x.a
```

This produces "2010-11-19 17:20:29.000"

I know you are using Date type and Time type, but same idea.