# How do I modify this query to also return Column D

Tags: sql

```
SELECT   ColA, MAX(CONVERT(varchar(15),ColB) + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar(15),ColC))
FROM     dbo.TableX
GROUPBY  ColA
```

Comment: where is column D ?  SELECT ColD,................ is enough :)

Comment: Sample input and expected output will help clarify the requirement

Comment: If you have specific needs, you need to specify them.  Saying "I want Column D" then complaining when the answers don't work because of undisclosed relationships is unhelpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RE: Your comment "This causes rows to be returned that have non-unique ColA."

Looking at [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227841/what-sql-query-returns-the-row-with-the-most-recent-date-and-time-column-b-and-c) I think you need something like

```
;WITH X AS
(
SELECT   ColA, 
         ColD,
         RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ColA ORDER BY CONVERT(varchar(15),ColB) + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar(15),ColC) DESC) Rnk
FROM     dbo.TableX
)
SELECT ColA, ColD, Rnk
FROM X
WHERE Rnk = 1;
```

Comment: Absolutely what I was looking for.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT 
    ColA, MAX(CONVERT(varchar(15),ColB) + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar(15),ColC)), 
    ColD 
FROM 
    dbo.TableX 
GROUP BY 
    ColA, ColD
```

Comment: This causes rows to be returned that have non-unique ColA.

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: @marc_s - thanks, i never remember to format SQL